# Add Chardin plugin to Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have some code looks like:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() { $('body').chardinJs('start') });

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'f'
      });

} );
```

(This is only JS/Jquery part in Jsfiddle added a whole)
http://jsfiddle.net/wAUKV/18/ 
As You can see when I click a 'tip' image the charding plugin will start and show some tips for my website section. The problem comes when I want to add notes to the DOM DataTables.
How I can solved this problem?

Comment: What problems exactly? Here is a working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/x3zq481v/ (remember to use https://rawgithub.com in fiddles, not https://raw.github.com) adding `data-intro` to columns works ...?

Comment: Hmm, yeah I dont say what problem exactly I have. Hmm When I click tip button I want to add tips only for 'search' in my Datatables (not for all width page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is that the different controls are injected into the `.dataTables_wrapper` element after initialisation. To add chardin text to the search box only (left to the "search" `<input>`) :

```
$(".dataTables_filter input")
   .attr("data-intro", "Type here to search in the table")
   .attr("data-position", "left");
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/La4a93vv/**

---

"loop" is called the lengthmenu :

```
$(".dataTables_length")
   .attr("data-intro", "Select number of visible rows")
   .attr("data-position", "right");
```

your fiddle updated -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wAUKV/33/**

Simply just inspect the injected markup to see what elements (=selectors) you should use to add "chardins".

Comment: Ok. It's work for this example, but when I add another plugin in to my Datatables? For example loop: http://jsfiddle.net/wAUKV/30/

Comment: Ok, I got this, Thank You ! :)

Comment: Ok It's worked, but when I add language plugin to my DataTable it does not work. :/

Comment: hey @mdk, it should not inflict on anything at all that you use different languages -> **http://jsfiddle.net/La4a93vv/3/**, the injected elements always have the same classes / names regardless of the language.

Comment: Yeah, You have right @davidkonrad, but the problem occurs when I use url option in language. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/La4a93vv/5/

Comment: hey @mdk- this is due to javascript asynchronicity :  When using a remote language file the initialisation of the dataTable is not finished before the chardin attr-attachments, it takes a little bit longer - you could use a `setTimeout` or even better a `initComplete` callback -> **http://jsfiddle.net/La4a93vv/7/**

Comment: Wow, Thank You again @davidkonrad ! :)